# MediaSource API not installed in chrome version 27

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc, media-source

I have chrome version 27 and according to this [link](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/mediasource/) MediaSource API is installed by default. Then in the same page the test section says that 
`Your browser does not support the MediaSource API`

Please help me out.

Comment: You may need to tweak chrome://flags/. Do you need to use Chrome 27? Chrome Stable is now 31. Does http://simpl.info/mse work?

Comment: No @SamDutton its not working it says `The MediaSource API is not available on this platform`.I am using ubuntu 12.04 . Do you insist on upgrading chrome?

Comment: Did you check the flags? (And can you update Chrome? Not sure about this specific platform/version.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade chrome to version31 and they start tweaking with chrome://flags

```
Disable unprefixed Media Source API. Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
Disable the unprefixed MediaSource object. This object allows JavaScript to send media data directly to a video element. #disable-unprefixed-media-source
```

In my older version (version27) the above option was not there, check that and MediaSource API is up and running.